# Convert string part of object to object Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object which has **strings** as values, but I want to convert them to **objects**.

Here is a working example of the object in question.

```
var test = {
    val1: "[{"test":"testval","test2": "testval2"}]",
    val2: "[{"test":"testval","test2": "testval2"}]",
    val3: "[{"test":"testval","test2": "testval2"}]"
}
```

I have tried `JSON.parse(test)` and...

```
var output;
for(var key in test){
    output += JSON.parse(test[key]);
}
```

**TLDR:** Want to "unstring" the object values to make them an (sub)object.

Comment: what do you want to achieve with `output += `?

Comment: All and everything is an object in JavaScript.

Comment: This is not valid JS: `val1: "[{"test":"testval","test2": "testval2"}]",` - perhaps you meant `val1: '[{"test":"testval","test2": "testval2"}]',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
for(var key in test){
    test[key] = JSON.parse(test[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Operator `=+` do not work with objects as you expect.
Check `{a:1} + {b:2}` in console.

You should create empty object. Then set parsed JSON strings as properties.

This will work.

```
var output = {};
for(var key in test){
    output[ key ] = JSON.parse(test[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are trying to parse an object and not a string. `JSON.parse` doesn't work on object but a JSON string.

Also, there is a syntax error that you are using `"` instead of `'` to specify the JSON strings. Change your code as below:

```js
var test = {
    val1: '[{"test":"testval","test2": "testval2"}]',
    val2: '[{"test":"testval","test2": "testval2"}]',
    val3: '[{"test":"testval","test2": "testval2"}]'
}

var output = {};
for(var key in test){
  output[key]= JSON.parse(test[key]);
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a for-loop.

Your "String" values do not seem to be valid JavaScript. Please make sure you start with a single quote or escape the double-quotes.

```js
var test = {
    val1: '[{"test":"testval","test2":"testval2"}]',
    val2: '[{"test":"testval","test2":"testval2"}]',
    val3: '[{"test":"testval","test2":"testval2"}]'
};

// Convert all values to objects.
Object.keys(test).forEach(key => test[key] = JSON.parse(test[key]));

// Print modified object.
console.log(JSON.stringify(test, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top:0; max-height:100% !important; }
```